# How to find element of textfield with selenium WebDriver?

Tags: java, selenium

I have already an example with google. Explain me please, what means `.findElement(By.name("q"));` how do WD understand that it's text field?

```
 WebDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is selecting an element with the value `q` for its `name` attribute.  It does not know that the element is an `input` it is only assigning it to the type `WebElement`.

If you want to determine if it is an `input` you can call [WebElement#getTagName](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getTagName%28%29) and get its type via [WebElement#getAttribute()](http://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29)

**Example**

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

// And now use this to visit Google
driver.get("http://www.google.com");

// Find the text input element by its name
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

if (element.getTagName().equalsIgnoreCase("input") 
        && element.getAttribute("type").equalsIgnoreCase("text")) {
    System.out.println("its a textbox");
}
```